# How to update a value in a map if it exists else insert it

Tags: java

I did a search and was amazed this hadn't been asked before (at least I couldn't find it).

I have a map like this:

```
Map<String, String> myMap
```

I know that I can check if a key exists within the map using`containsKey(Object key);` and I can replace a value using `replace(String key, String value);` and naturally put a value using `put(String key, String value);`

Now if I want to check a value if it exists update it, else insert it, I have to use a condition:

```
if(myMap.containsKey(key)) {
    myMap.replace(key, value);
} else {
    myMap.put(key, value);
}
```

Is there a  better way of doing this? I personally feel the condition is a bit unnecessary and overcomplicating something which could be one line rather than five!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The replace will be done by `put()`:

From the documentation of [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V))

> public V put(K key,
>       V value)  Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the
>   old value is replaced.

So you only need

```
myMap.put(key, value);
```

Comment: shouldn't replace method be obsolete?

Answer (score 6):

Remove all the code and below line is enough.

```
myMap.put(key, value);
```

That already checks and replaces if any value exist already.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the `#put()` method, it will replace the existing item if there is one. By the way `AbstractMap` (the superclass of `HashMap`) implements `#replace()` this way:

```
default boolean replace(K key, V oldValue, V newValue) {
     Object curValue = get(key);
     if (!Objects.equals(curValue, oldValue) ||
         (curValue == null && !containsKey(key))) {
         return false;
     }
     put(key, newValue);
     return true;
 }
```

In your case, you don't need the extra checks of this method.

Comment: Good for Educate & Inform...not everyone looks at the source implementation, or its "parent-age" for insight.

Answer (score 2):

in java 8 , there is a good way to do this

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

      map.put("count", map.getOrDefault("count", 0) + 1);

}
System.out.println(map.get("count"));
```